# R-Tree construction algorithm using polygon MBR

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, r-tree

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to construct an R-Tree when I have all the known Minimum Bounding Rectangles (MBR) of the polygons in my set. The R-Tree would be ideal for storing these spatial references to eliminate my current brute force inspecting for polygon intersection:

```
for p1 in polygons: # O(n)
    for p2 in polygons: # O(n)
        if p2 is not p1: # O(1)
            if p2.intersects(p1): # O(1); computed using DeMorgans law on vertices
                # do stuff
```

Does anybody have a reference that denotes methods of how to determine the partitioning of the rectangles that encompass the MBRs of the polygons in the set?

Comment: Same as for points. Because at the next level of the tree, each page is a MBR.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse As in my comment to the answer below, my real issue is determining which rectangles are to be grouped. I'm having trouble conceptualizing that detail.

Comment: Read the STR paper. If I am not mistaken, it simply uses the center points of rectangles. But you can look this up.

Answer (score 0):

There are many R-Tree partitioning algorithm, in my experience the best one is R*Tree (R-Star-Tree) by Beckmann et al. Just search for ["The R*-tree: an efficient and robust access method for points and rectangles"](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+R*-tree%3A+an+efficient+and+robust+access+method+for+points+and+rectangles).

If you prefer reading code, there are also many open-source implementations, including [my own one in Java](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/tree/master/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index/rtree). Be warned though, the R*Tree algorithm is not trivial.

If you are looking for something simpler, try quadtrees or octrees. If insertion and update speed is top priority, have a look at the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) (again my own implementation), but it also more complicated than quadtrees.

Another simpler solution is the [AABB-Tree](https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/introductory-guide-to-aabb-tree-collision-detection/), it's like an R-Tree but with only two bounding boxes per node. It's used a lot in computer graphics I think, but I don't know much about it except that it is relatively simple for an R-Tree.

**EDIT** (Update to answer comment)

If you are looking for a bulk loading strategy such as STR, [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e680/839472e7f5cab0f12fcc7c4aba6834a2e096.pdf) is the original paper. You can have a look at my R-Tree implementation, as it also provides an [implementation of an STR-Loader](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index/rtree/STRLoader.java) that can handle points and rectangles.

Searching stack overflow I also found [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/bulk-loading-r-tree-with-data-with-extent) which apparently points to an alternative bulk loader specifically for storing rectangles.

I would like to point out that bulk loading (such as STR-Loading) is the fasted way to load an R-Tree. However, in my own experiments (see [Figure 3 here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf)), this is still 2-3 times slower than a good quadtree or a PH-Tree.

Comment: I was looking for the implementations of the bulk loading, or packing, of the R-Tree; such as Nearest-X or STR, I don't need a dynamic tree.

Comment: Thank you for update. After reading the papers supplied, I suppose I am confused as to how the "pages" are built. You must specify a maximum number of pages per leaf, and each page points to a new leaf. So in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) why is it that some leafs have only 2 pages but some have 3?

Comment: An AABB-Tree is probably a good start for me. The issue I have trouble conceptualizing is how to decide which rectangles group together. In the AABB-Tree example, obviously 1 and 3 go together, but how is that decided?

Comment: In the wiki example, 2 is the minimum entries per page/node (pages are the same as nodes), the maximum is 3. If you have more than 3 you need to split. If you have less then 2 (after removal) you merge.

Comment: In the AABB page it says "A common heuristic used here is to assign a cost to the surface area of the left and right nodes having been adjusted for the addition of the new leaf’s AABB and descend in the direction of the cheapest node until you find yourself on a leaf.". In other words, when inserting a new element, you calculate how much the surface of each node's AABB has to grow to encompass the new element. Then you insert the element into the node that has to grow the least.

Comment: How should one determine the maximum number of entries per page/node in an R-tree?

Comment: If you store the tree on a harddrive, you would select the number of entries such that they fit into a sector/page. For in-memory, I would determine it experimentally to see what gives the best performance. I found values between 5 and 10 to perform quite good.

Comment: It would be in-memory (I wouldnt even know how to determine if entries fit into a sector/page), and thats what I figured. None of the papers specified how to determine/set the number of pages per node, let alone the maximum number of entries per page. Looks like both are experimentally set (such as in the R-Tree wiki where there are 3 pages per node in the graphic).